# How to escape "@" when reading from a JSON response?

Tags: json, escaping

Let's say I have below sample JSON response from which I want to extract value for "@type":

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "@type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "@type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Validated using:- http://jsonpath.com/

This works for "number":

```
$.phoneNumbers.[number]
```

But cannot get value for "@type":

```
$.phoneNumbers.[@type]
```

Tried multiple ways but no luck.

Thanks!

Edits:- added another value in the array for "home", now indexing logic [0,1] doesn't work. Even tried with [:] to fetch all values, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in [this documentation](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

> Please note, that the return value of jsonPath is an array, which is
> also a valid JSON structure.

So basically it always returns an array.

```
var phoneTypes = jsonPath(json,"$.phoneNumbers.[@type]");
```

result

```
["iPhone","home"]
```

if you want one phone you have to use phoneTypes[0] for iPhone

but I higly recommend you to fix your json using this code

```
var fixedJson=  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).replaceAll("\"@type\"","\"type\"" ));
```

in this case you can use the real search

```
var homePhone = jsonPath(fixedJson,"$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type =='home')]")[0].number;
```

output

```
0123-4567-8910
```

Comment: never mind, this one worked :- $.phoneNumbers.[0][@type]

Comment: but still it has problem since array would have more than 1 values and even after changing that to a colon(:) instead of index value (0,1) to consider all values, it doesn't work:- $.phoneNumbers.[:][@type]

Comment: @ManiK I updated my answer You are not using my path , this is your problem. Why you are asking for help then ?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned am using this online tool to validate my Json response & output:- http://jsonpath.com/ , so it's specifically this online tool where I am not able to validate the results.

Comment: @ManiK It is up to you. This code  was tested and working. But  it  seems it doesn't matter for you , you are testing online service, not your code